# Adding captions to multiple images in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny you can add images from disk using the line below. I also found that a tag called `figcaption` or `caption` can be used to add captions to the images. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find an example on how to structure `figcaption`. How can I add captions right under multiple images in a shiny app? The code below stacks the captions one under the other instead of placing them under each figure respectively.

```
ui = navbarPage("Project Eddy", theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
               div((img(src = "Study_Area.png", height = '640px', width = '480px'),img(src = "Picture1.png", height = '640px', width = '480px'),img(src = "Picture2.png", height = '640px', width = '480px')),
            div(tags$figcaption("Figure 1: Ed), tags$figcaption("Figure 2: Edd), tags$figcaption("Figure 3: Eddy")),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be trickier than I expected.  Looking at the spec for the `<figcaption>` [HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption), it needs to be the *first* or *last* element of the parent `<figure>` tag.  Shiny's `renderPlot()` function doesn't wrap its image in a `<figure>` tag.  Maybe there's a way of coercing `renderPlot()` to do this, but I couldn't find it.  I resorted to using `renderUI()` and manually constructing the necessary nested `tag`s.

Here's a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
        uiOutput("all")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  d1 <- tibble(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
  d2 <- tibble(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
  
  output$all <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      uiOutput("plot1"),
      uiOutput("plot2")
    )
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    tags$figure(
      htmltools::plotTag(
        d2 %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)), 
        alt="Plot 1"
      ), 
      tags$figcaption("This is plot 1"))
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderUI({
    tags$figure(
      htmltools::plotTag(
        d2 %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)), 
        alt="Plot 2"
      ), 
      tags$figcaption("This is plot 2"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So, how should I connect this with div((img(src = "Study_Area.png", height = '640px', width = '480px'),img(src = "Picture1.png", height = '640px', width = '480px'),img(src = "Picture2.png", height = '640px', width = '480px'))?

Comment: `height` and `width` are optional arguments to `plotTag()`.  To supply a static image from a file, you should be able to pass an expression that yields the image as `expr`, the first argument to `plotTag()` in place of my `... %>% ggplot() ...`.

Comment: Can you please edit your code to reflect that? Thank you